# Why does Americium-241 not exist naturally?

Tags: cosmology, universe, radioactivity, half-life

A few searches says that it's because "the half life is too short with respect to the age of the universe." I don't understand what that means.

Note that the half life of Americium-241 is 470 years.

Comment: Imagine every atom in the observable universe was americium-$241$, say $10^{87}$ of them. How long before only one of them is? (Answer: 136 kyr, less than a hundred-thousandth of the universe's age.)

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for the answer, just wondering - how did you get 136 kyr? I would like to calculate what the minimum half life would be for a radioactive isotope to exist naturally.

Comment: was it $10^{87} = 2^x$, solve for $x$ then multiply by half life?

Comment: Bear in mind that throughout the Universe's industry only a few nuclides have comprised more than a very tiny percentage of all atoms, and "there's one atom of it left somewhere" isn't much good to us; if you're looking to still detect some on Earth, you can really only afford about ten half-lives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing specific to Americium-241 but to any radioactive isotope. Half of them decay within their half-life (thus the name). Therefore, after a few half-lifes, all are gone (Just calculate e.g. $2^{10}$...), unless there is some mechanism that keeps producing them. For Americium-241, that is not the case, so even if you had produced some somehow in the past, after a few thousand years, all is gone: No Americium-241 exists naturally.